# Excel: How to get dates out of a an excel row

Tags: excel, parsing, date, rows

How can I extract the begin/end date from an Excel row?

There should be no overlaps or gaps in the begin and end dates.  There are several begin and end dates that it must go between and grab the earliest date.

Also need to validate the begin/end dates.  There are several records and they may have the same or different beginning and end times, when pulling them together I need the earliest date/time to be pulled and displayed. It will do the same for the end date, earliest date/time. For the next row, the begin date will be the same as the previous rows end date, and so forth.

I'm trying to get an algorithm for Excel.  Should I be using SQL to do this or can I keep it in Excel?

Here are three example sets of data, and the fourth one is what I'd like for the results to be.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? You might want to look into VBA macros. Try recording the macro to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**In Excel split or parse the text content on a delimiter like comma or space:**

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/split-names-by-using-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-HA010102340.aspx

**Use Excel's Text To Column Feature:**

In Excel, Go to Data menu and click "Text to column" and follow the wizard.

**You can also split text in Excel using functions:**

Put some text delimited by spaces in cell A1.

Put the following into cell B1:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1))
```

That will parse out the first word in cell A1.